# Ошибка при поиске элементов по присвоенным классам

Tags: javascript

HTML документ содержит указание на две функции, которые выстреливают при загрузке и единственный контейнер `div`:

```
<body onload="buildBlockTaker(), setDefaultBlockTaker();">
  <div id="takerBlocksContainer"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

Первая функция создает 3 контейнера, присваивает каждому из них разный класс и цепляет каждый из них к элементу `takerBlocksContainer`

```
function buildBlockTaker() {
  item1 = document.createElement("div");
  item2 = document.createElement("div");
  item3 = document.createElement("div");

  item1.classList += "name";
  item2.classList += "inn";
  item3.classList += "ogrn";

  takerBlocksContainer.appendChild(item1);
  takerBlocksContainer.appendChild(item2);
  takerBlocksContainer.appendChild(item3);
}
```

Вторая функция перебирает потомков `takerBlocksContainer`. Если у потомка есть хотя бы один из классов `name inn ogrn`, то выводится положительное сообщение в консоли. Если нет - то отрицательное

```
function setDefaultBlockTaker(index) {
  let childCollection = takerBlocksContainer.children;

  for (i = 0; i < childCollection.length; i++) {
    if (childCollection[i].classList.contains("name" || "inn" || "ogrn")) {
      console.log('matches: ', childCollection[i]);
      console.log('fitting classes ', childCollection[i].classList);
    } else {
      console.log("doesn't match: ", childCollection[i]);
      console.log('not fitting classes ', childCollection[i].classList);
    }
  }
}
```

В результате проходит только контейнер с классом `name`, `inn` и `ogrn` не проходят. Я подозреваю, что ошибка в неправильной записи оператора или - `||`, но не могу понять в чем дело. Как исправить код?

Бонусный вопрос: считается ли допустимым использовать CSS классы не для присваивания стилей элементам, а исключительно как родовой идентификатор для элементов для целей javascript в противовес уникальным идентификаторам `id` Или для этого используется атрибут `name` или что-то еще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно исправить вот так:

```
if (childCollection[i].classList.contains("name") ||
childCollection[i].classList.contains("inn") ||
childCollection[i].classList.contains("ogrn") ){
    console.log('matches: ', childCollection[i]);
    console.log('fitting classes ',childCollection[i].classList);
}
```

Что касается второго вопроса, то да, допускается. Некоторые создают отдельные классы для использования в CSS и JS, например:

```
<div class="item js-item"></div>
```

Где `item` используется для стилизации, а `js-item` для использования в js. Но по большому счету это все зависит от предпочтений конкретного разработчика.
Помимо этого, можно использовать `data-*` атрибуты для хранения информации, относящейся к конкретному элементу, которую вы в дальнейшем планируете использовать в коде.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что `.contains` является по сути просто функцией и не предусматривает в себе логических выражений в качестве аргументов, а конструкция if...else прямо предусматривает, верно?

Comment: Да, метод `.contains` ожидает строку на вход. Выражение `"name" || "inn" || "ogrn"` возвратит первый истинный элемент - "name", то есть на вход функции contains будет всегда попадать "name" в данном случае.